# What type of technology can I program to do the same as this site about recording my login?

Tags: cookies

What type of technology can I program to do the same as this site about recording my login even when I clean the cookies and every stuff of my browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create cookies that are remarkably persistent, even when the user attempts to delete them, check out [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/)

Comment: evercookie is evil! Clever, but evil.

Comment: nice, this is problably how they did.
but damn, this thing shouldn't be used :P

Comment: Thanks. Something new for my blacklist. Opera has options that deal with this

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange sites are using [HTML 5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for that. You may want to check out the following for further details:

- [Stack Overflow Blog: Global Network Auto-Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)
- [Meta Stack Overflow: How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work)